# Group by in c# ..here i only getting data inside the select clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, group-by, automapper

Here is the code I have for grouping data based on `Fkitemid` in `salelines`.  With my current code, `group by` and `sum` are working correctly.

But the final result set only has the properties that are mentioned in the curly brackets of `select`.  Only these properties are getting mapped.  I am only getting data included in the `select`.

But I used `context.include` before `select`.

I need to get the data in `salelines` too.

What changes to my code do I need to accomplish this?

````cs
var model = await _context.Saleslines
    .Include(x => x.Fkitem)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Fkcategory)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Fkitemid).Select(x =>
        new SaleslineVM
        {
            Fkitemid = x.Key,
            Totalqty = x.Sum(y => y.Qty),
                                
        }).ToListAsync();
mappedModel = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SaleslineVM>>(model);
return View(GetFilteredData(mappedModel, Datefrom, Dateto, FkitemidRendertype, box));```
````

Comment: ```.Select()``` basically extracts only the things you specify in it. In your case those are ```Fkitemid``` and ```Totalqty```. If you want anything else you will have to include it.

Comment: @IvanGechev how iam able add there ..i cant add there by using .include() or .select() and idont want to use sum()..can you please show the way too add price from saleslines in .select{}

Comment: I will need more info about the models you have, particularly ```Saleslines```, also, it is not really clear what else you want to include.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: @IvanGechev  i want to add Fkitem in the salelines..In model(salelines) Fkitem is defined like  –                                                                                                                
 public virtual Item Fkitem { get; set; }                                                                                  can you please suggest a way..iam new to dotnet

Comment: Do you have the ```public virtual Item Fkitem { get; set; }``` in the ```SaleslineVM```? If yes, you might try ```Fkitem = x.Fkitem``` in the ```Select```. If not, you'll have to add it in the ```SaleslineVM``` and then assign it in the ```Select```.

Comment: @IvanGechev i can't use Fkitem = x.Fkitem.. in x dot there is only functions like sum,select,list etc..

Comment: @IvanGechev yes ,there is Fkitem in salelineVM

Comment: @muhammed nihal what does ```x.Value``` contain then?

Comment: @IvanGechev  there is no "Value in x dot... there is only methods ,extenstion methods and properties like  All, Append ,Cast,Contact,Count